# IPv6 MTU and MSS ignored in LAN?

Tags: routing, ipv6, linux-networking

I have a server with a (sixxs) IPv6 tunnel and a local network behind it. The tunnel has MTU of 1470, and a prefix with this MTU is advertised by radvd, and picked up by the local client:

```
root@host:~# ip -6 route
2001:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 298sec mtu 1470
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1470
default via fe80::dad3:85ff:feaf:7e77 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 28sec mtu 1470 hoplimit 64
```

The interface of the client has MTU of 1500, as usual. Now, when I transfer a file to a remote IPv6 host, the following happens (wireshark packet dump on the server, LAN interface, of relevant part):

```
15.034320 host -> remote SSHv2 Encrypted request packet len=2796
15.034408 server -> host ICMPv6 Too big
15.241163 host -> remote SSHv2 [TCP Retransmission] Encrypted request packet len=1398
15.252193 remote -> host TCP ssh > 58188 [ACK] Seq=2658 Ack=121902 Win=64128 Len=0 TSV=2205083594 TSER=4294965684
15.252480 host -> remote SSHv2 [TCP Retransmission] Encrypted request packet len=2796
15.252558 server -> host ICMPv6 Too big
15.461151 host -> remote SSHv2 [TCP Retransmission] Encrypted request packet len=1398
```

So, the host sends a packet of size 2796 (should not even be possible, the link MTU is 1500), and the server correctly replies with ICMPv6 Too big. The packet is then re-transmitted with the correct size and acknowledged. But then, the next packet is again too big, and the process repeats indefinitely, while the file is transferred at a snail's pace... What is happening here? The route cache shows that the MTU of the route is picked up correctly (IPv6 addresses replaced with names):

```
root@host:~# ip -6 route show cached
remote via fe80::dad3:85ff:feaf:7e77 dev eth1  metric 0 
    cache  mtu 1470 hoplimit 64
server via server dev eth1  metric 0 
    cache  mtu 1470
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, at home more weird issues were happening in the network. I took the Microsoft way and rebooted the server. Problem seems gone.